# Clean fix to KeyError NoneType while parsing JSON

Tags: python, json, twitter, nonetype

I'm pretty noob and using some borrowed python code for a very simple JSON parse of tweets I pulled with tweepy. I've tried solving myself but seem to be creating more problems.

Just a few lines in the .txt file cause problems. On the one hand, the file contains this periodically:

> {"limit":{"track":3,"timestamp_ms":"1487481419833"}}

On the other hand, for some tweets the tweet fields are all there but seems to not be in JSON format (e.g. Sublime doesn't recognize the syntax as such).

The result is the below code gives me a KeyError 'text'

```
tweets['text'] = map(lambda tweet: tweet['text'], tweets_data)
```

So I fix that by changing it to:

```
tweets['text'] = map(lambda tweet: tweet.get('text', None), tweets_data)
```

However, now I get a different error later in my code when use:

```
def word_in_text(word, text):
word = word.lower()
text = text.lower()
match = re.search(word, text)
if match:
    return True
return False
```

I get the error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'

I figure there must be a cleaner, simpler fix to all this. Any suggestions? Below is the full code (minus some charts I'm printing and few more columns I created in the dataFrame).

Many thanks, and apologies if I haven't got the proper posting etiquette.

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import re

tweets_data_path = '[...trump_tweets.txt]'

tweets_data = []
tweets_file = open(tweets_data_path, "r")
for line in tweets_file:
try:
    tweet = json.loads(line)
    tweets_data.append(tweet)
except:
    continue

print "Number of tweets included is " + str(len(tweets_data))

tweets = pd.DataFrame()

tweets['text'] = map(lambda tweet: tweet.get('text', None), tweets_data)
tweets['lang'] = map(lambda tweet: tweet.get('lang', None), tweets_data)
tweets['country'] = map(lambda tweet: tweet.get('place', None), tweets_data)

def word_in_text(word, text):
word = word.lower()
text = text.lower()
match = re.search(word, text)
if match:
    return True
return False

search_term_1 = 'America'
search_term_2 = 'POTUS'
search_term_3 = 'ban'

tweets[search_term_1] = tweets['text'].apply(lambda tweet: word_in_text(search_term_1, tweet))
tweets[search_term_2] = tweets['text'].apply(lambda tweet: word_in_text(search_term_2, tweet))
tweets[search_term_3] = tweets['text'].apply(lambda tweet: word_in_text(search_term_3, tweet))

print "tweets mentioning search_term_1: " + str(tweets[search_term_1].value_counts()[True])
print "tweets mentioning search_term_2: " + str(tweets[search_term_2].value_counts()[True])
print "tweets mentioning search_term_3: " + str(tweets[search_term_3].value_counts()[True])
```

Comment: Probably one of the tweets has no text? have you tried to print the tweets and look into the rebellious one?

Comment: @omri_saadon Yes I can see the problem in fact--that's what I tried to explain at top. There is an occasional "limit" stamp in the .txt file, and other tweets don't appear in the proper syntax (for those I'd guess a field is missing or something).

Comment: In that case, I guess you get rateLimitException, is that true? What do you wish to accomplish? to avoid the error or not iterate over malformed tweets?

Comment: Thanks, I was getting the error **KeyError 'text'** I suppose I want to avoid the error and move on, and I think the @gryf code does that. (Removing those lines from the .txt file would be great too but not essential)

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
tweets['text'] = map(lambda tweet: tweet.get('text', ''), tweets_data)
```

Dictionary method `.get()` by default return `None` in case of missing key, but it might be any object. In this case tweet['text'] is possibly a string, so it might be a good idea to put empty for missing one.

Comment: Ah so simple, thanks! That seems to get me through it. Do you know why this other line won't work similarly? `tweets['country'] = map(lambda tweet: tweet.get('place', '')('country', '') if tweet.get('place', '') != None else None, tweets_data)`

Comment: this: `tweet.get('place', '')('country', '')` seem like calling a function, which probably is not what you want. this `if tweet.get('place', '') != None` will never be `None`.